# Show no errors on validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

Plain and simple:

How do I validate fields but don't show any errors for those? I need to validate nested attributes and validate them, but not show any error messages.

Comment: You want error messages to be not shown or so they don't stop saving?

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel Validations should still apply, but without error messages.

Comment: if you want this on particular page just comment out `<%= error_messages_for 'user' %>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand you correctly, just go to your view where the code for printing the errors are, and remove it.

If  created by scaffold, they are located inside the forms of your models, (`_form.html.erb`). Remove the code where it loops the error messages from the model.

**UPDATE**

You can too, put a `after_validation` filter on your model, that clears the errors array.

```
def model
  after_validate :clear_errors_array

  def clear_errors_array
    @model.errors.clear
  end
```

Comment: I thought of that, but then again I need to do that in every view in which I display the errors. I'd rather have a solution in my model.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Didn't know the clear method yet. That solved it!